# Random pixels? (Matrices, Numpy)

Tags: numpy, matrix, pixel, numpy-ndarray

I'm experimenting with numpy and I'd like to ask a solution for the following code. I'd like to, actually, generate a 256x256 image, from start using a random rgb schema -- probably that would be the way to go. Any numpy insights would be welcome!

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

def transform_matrice(data):

    aux_data = []

    for e in data:
        aux = []
        for a in e:
            aux.append(np.array([[random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255)]]))
        aux_data.append(aux)

    return aux_data

w, h = 250, 250
data = np.zeros((h, w, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

ret = transform_matrice(data)

img = Image.fromarray(ret, 'RGB')
img.save('eg.png')
img.show()
```

with this code I got the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '__array_interface__'
```

Comment: Maybe `randImage= np.random.randint(0,256,(255,255,3), dtype=np.uint8)`

Comment: "Images, matrices, numpy" can you please make a title that briefly explains your question?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create a empty `data` table neither you need to use `for` loops, numpy can do it for you!
[`np.random.randint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) will create you a 3D matrix of size (w,h,3) with integers from 0 to 255 using the following command:

```
def transform_matrice(w,h):
        return np.random.randint(0,256,size=(w,h,3)).astype('uint8')

ret = transform_matrice(250,250)
```

None that I put 256 and not 255 as second parameter since the parameter is one above the largest integer you want